# String as 2 D array

Tags: php, arrays, string, variables, substring

I'm using PHP, and I get a string from a db with a struct similar to this:
$string = "a:b;c:d;e:f;g:h;" and so on, where a, b, c.. are variables,
a,c and e couldn't be a continuous number, they can be numbers from 1 to 500.
 I need to convert this string into an array with this format:

```
$array [a] == ("b");
$array [c] == ("d");
$array [e] == ("f");
```

etc...

But I don't know how to get two substring from string (double dot separated, and dot comma separated) and put it into a 2 D string.

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manipulate the keys and the values of the resulting array without foreach loop,  you can use [array_reduce](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$string = "a:b;c:d;e:f;g:h;";

$array = array_reduce( array_filter( explode( ';', $string ) ), function( $result, $item ) {
    $tmp = explode( ':', $item );
    $result[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];
    return $result;
});
```

output:

```
Array (
    [a] => b
    [c] => d
    [e] => f
    [g] => h 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

use `explode()` which will [split a string into an array based on the specified delimiter](https://www.php.net/explode).

```
$string = "a:b;c:d;e:f;g:h;";
$temparray = explode(';', $string);
//$temparray now looks like ['a:b', 'c:d', 'e:f']
//use explode() again in a loop to split up each index

$finalarray = array();
foreach($temparray as $arr){
  $splitarr = explode(':', $arr);
  //$splitarr will look something like ['a', 'b']
  //use those values to set the indexes in your final array
  $finalarray[$splitarr[0]] = $splitarr[1];
}
$finalarray=array_filter($finalarray);//to remove null values
//print_r($finalarray);
```

NOTE:  Just FYI, because of the trailing `;` in your string, you may end up with an extra empty index at the end of your arrays, hence the `array_filter()` call, thanks @FerozAkbar

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you are asking,but this may helps you

```
$re = '/(.?):(.?)/'; 
$str = 'a:b;c:d;e:f;g:h;'; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);

print_r(array_combine($matches[1],$matches[2]));
```

***output:***

```
(
    [a] => b
    [c] => d
    [e] => f
    [g] => h
)
```